Convertir imagen.jpg a color en imagen en escala de grises en Javascript

El objetivo del código: cargar una imagen que está alojada en la  misma carpeta que el archivo index.html, convertirla a escalas de grises y mostrarla en el canvas.

El problema: la imagen no se transforma permanece igual.

A saber:
3.1 He instalado un localhost con python para correr index.html. Esto funciona bien.
3.2 Archivo index.html y "h.jpg" están en la misma carpeta
3.3 Esto es lo que informa Visual Studio:

Uncaught DOMException SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
at blanco_negro (c:\temp\index.html:29:24)
at imageLoaded (c:\temp\index.html:21:4)
--- load ---
at  (c:\temp\index.html:10:16)

3.4 El código lo fui escribiendo siguiendo este tutorial hasta el minuto 10:00. Url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huPO8RxvuEo&t=605s&ab_channel=RingaTech

El código:


    var image = new Image();
        image.onload = imageLoaded;
        image.src = "h.jpg";

        function imageLoaded()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0, image.width, image.height );

            blanco_negro(canvas);
            

        }// end function imageLoaded

        function blanco_negro(canvas)
        {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var pixeles = imageData;

            for( var p =0;p < pixeles.length; p+= 4)// avanzo de a 4 pq cada pixel ocupa 4 posiciones contiguas en el array pixeles
            {
                var rj = pixeles[p];
                var vd = pixeles[p+1];
                var az = pixeles[p+2];
                var alf = pixeles[p+3];

                var gris = (rj + vd + az )/3;

                pixeles[p] = gris;
                pixeles[p+1] = gris;
                pixeles[p+2] = gris;

            }// end for p < pixeles.length  

            ctx.putImageData(imageData,0 ,0);
            //console.log(imageData);
        }// end function blanco_negro


Agradecer la ayuda

Saludos a todos.

Muchas gracias por tu edición de mi pregunta. Soy nuevo en esto asi que toca aprender el estilo correcto a usar.

Este error yo también lo tengo en hacer algo parecido.
Lo que falla es el método getImageData que no accede cuando el grafico no es un dibujo ( cuando es una imagen ).
Si pruebas a hacer un dibujo verás que entonces tus métodos funcionan por la parte del grafico que si has coloreado.

El problema es que necesitas usar un servidor http para que funcione: cuando el navegador usa direcciones URL que son realmente accesos al sistema de ficheros local, no considera seguro ninguno de los recursos obtenidos. Te pongo tu código con imágenes obtenidas de la red y arreglando un par de detallitos en tu código:


const image = new Image();
image.onload = imageLoaded;

// Necesario para este ejemplo, el dominio de StackOverflow y el dominio de la imagen no coinciden
image.crossOrigin="";

image.src = "https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/28/200/150.jpg?hmac=wz38-hHVadpz_Iuoo0j68K_bUNeiChOWEfNQOZPc7Gc";

function imageLoaded()
{
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0,0, image.width, image.height );
    blanco_negro(canvas);
    

}// end function imageLoaded

function blanco_negro(canvas)
{
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    //IMPORTANTE, los datos están dentro de imageData
    const pixeles = imageData.data;

    for( let p =0;p < pixeles.length; p+= 4)// avanzo de a 4 pq cada pixel ocupa 4 posiciones contiguas en el array pixeles
    {
        const rj = pixeles[p];
        const vd = pixeles[p+1];
        const az = pixeles[p+2];
        
        const gris = (rj + vd + az )/3;

        pixeles[p] = gris;
        pixeles[p+1] = gris;
        pixeles[p+2] = gris;

    }// end for p < pixeles.length  

    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0 ,0);
    
}// end function blanco_negro
<img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/28/200/150.jpg?hmac=wz38-hHVadpz_Iuoo0j68K_bUNeiChOWEfNQOZPc7Gc"/>
<canvas id="canvas">



Notas finales:

Respondí una pregunta relacionada hace algún tiempo, puedes verla aquí: Resaltar un color especifico en una imagen

Recomiendo no usar var para declarar variables, es algo que hoy día es obsoleto y puede crear confusiones. Puedes leer un par de respuestas relacionadas con el tema:

¿Cuando conviene utilizar var, let y const en ECMA Script 6?
var, let, const... o nada en Javascript




Genial muchas gracias  Pablo por tu ayuda. Pensé que corriendo en localhost debería funcionar y así lo hace en el tutorial que estoy siguiendo. Este viernes tengo un concierto soy flautista así que la semana que viene me volveré a meter en el tema.  El código es una parte para programar una red neuronal convolucional en forma local y reconocer imágenes. Reitero muchas gracias y saludos a la comunidad.

"En localhost" funciona, pero usando http. Monta un pequeño server en tu máquina con node o NGNIX y podrás probarlo
